# Questions, explanation about Image uploader

Tags: magento2, image-upload

1. I want to know where can we set the maximum `image weight` upload in admin ?
2. Why don't we get the `error message` when we go past the allowed weight ?

   I noticed according to my tests that  the maximum weight of image is : `2 Mo`, the image is not uploaded and with an seccess message: `You saved the configuration.` bellow `2 Mo` the image is uploaded.
3. About **dimensions**, according to the `vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php`, The max width and height are :

   ```
   /**
    * Max Image Width resolution in pixels. For image resizing on client side
    */
   const MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH = 1920;

   /**
    * Max Image Height resolution in pixels. For image resizing on client side
    */
   const MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1200;
   ```

   But If I upload an  `2560x1440` size, the Image is well uploaded.

**system.xml**

```
<field id="1" translate="label" type="image" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" >
    <label>Image 1</label>
    <backend_model>Vendor\Name\Model\Config\Backend\Image</backend_model>
    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">home</base_url>
</field>
```

**Vendor\Name\Model\Config\Backend\Image\Image.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Name\Model\Config\Backend;

class Image extends \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Backend\Image
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory
     */
    protected $_imageFactory;

    /**
     * The tail part of directory path for uploading
     *
     */
    const UPLOAD_DIR = 'home'; // Folder save image

    /**
     * Return path to directory for upload file
     *
     * @return string
     * @throw \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _getUploadDir()
    {
        return $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($this->_appendScopeInfo(self::UPLOAD_DIR));
    }

    /**
     * Makes a decision about whether to add info about the scope.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    protected function _addWhetherScopeInfo()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for allowed extensions of uploaded files.
     *
     * @return string[]
     */
    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg'];
    }

}
```